# rtrim (trimming a string) in C

Tags: c, trim

I have a function:

```
char* rtrim(char* string, char junk)
{
    char* original = string + strlen(string);
    while(*--original == junk);
    *(original + 1) = '\0';
    return string;
}
```

Which I call like this:

```
colTok = rtrim(colTok,"%");
```

colTok is char * which contains string number like "80%". I need to remove the % . I believe I have used the function some time before but now it does not work because when I debug and enter into it, so junk is -49 'Ď' instead '%'. So what's the problem? What I do wrong?

Comment: Your function fails miserably for a string comprised of junk characters, eg: `char eg[] = "XXXXXXXX"; rtrim(eg, 'X');`

Comment: Code also fails when `string[0] == '\0'`. - for similar reasons as commented by @pmg

Answer (score 3):

```
colTok = rtrim(colTok,"%"); // "%" is a string
```

You need to pass a single character

```
colTok = rtrim(colTok, '%');
```

I suggest you always pay attention to your compiler warnings; assume they're errors.

Comment: "pay attention to your compiler warnings", which should be fully enabled, is the best part for OP.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're passing a string, not a char, to the function. Should be:

```
colTok = rtrim(colTok, '%');
```

The string `"%"` you passed, which is a char[], is having it's address being treated as a char. That's why the junk.

Comment: Thanks. I was convinced that I already used it but had completely forgotten how.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my rtrim in portable C99.

```c
const char* C_Whitespaces = " \t\n\r\f\v";

char* rtrim(char* s)
{
  char* r = s, * end;
  size_t len = strlen(s) - 1;
  for (end = s+len;
       strstr(C_Whitespaces, r+len) && end != s;
       end = s+len , *(r + (len--)) = 0);
  return r;
}
```